# Java issue; can't add activities to an ArrayList<???> Help needed

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, compilation, compiler-errors

I was preparing my test for Monday, but there are no answers. I have done well so far but i'm stuck now. I am clueless what to do.
Searched for ages on the internet but im missing a lil thing I guess..

Maybe you guys could help me out?

Question: I need to place the activities in a dayplanning ArrayList<...> 
and print them out I have no clue how to do this.

I've tried ArrayList Integers String I have no clue how the **** I do this :P
Goal run simulateOneDay() in GarageSimulation.

Tester.java

```
public class Tester {
public void equalsTest() {

    Car c1=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'p', 1800);
    Car c2=new Car("Citroen", "C5 Tourer", 'd', 2300);
    Car c3=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'd', 2050);
    System.out.println(c1.equals(c1));
    System.out.println(c1.equals(c2));
    System.out.println(c1.equals(c3));
    Bicycle b1=new Bicycle("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", false);
    Car c4=new Car("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", 'p', 950);
    System.out.println(c4.equals(b1));

    /* Expected outcome
    true
    false
    true
    false
     */
}

public void simulateOneDayTest() {

    Car c1=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'p', 1800);
    Car c2=new Car("Citroen", "C5 Tourer", 'd', 2300);
    Car c3=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'd', 2050);
    Bicycle b1=new Bicycle("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", false);
    Car c4=new Car("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", 'p', 950);
    Car c5=new Car("Hummer", "XL", 'd', 5600);
    Car c6=new Car("BMW", "R3", 'd', 6350);
    Car c7=new Car("Citroen", "C5 Tourer", 'd', 2300);

    GarageSimulation gs=new GarageSimulation();
    gs.addVehicle(c1);
    gs.addVehicle(c2);
    gs.addVehicle(c3);
    gs.addVehicle(b1);
    gs.addVehicle(c4);
    gs.addVehicle(c5);
    gs.addVehicle(c6);
    gs.addVehicle(c7);

    gs.simulateOneDay();

    /* Expected outcome
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 8:15
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 8:25
    Repairing takes 36 minutes
    Current time is 9:01
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 9:16
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 9:26
    Repairing takes 46 minutes
    Current time is 10:12
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 10:27
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 10:37
    Repairing takes 41 minutes
    Current time is 11:18
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 11:33
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 11:43
    Repairing takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 11:58
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 12:13
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 12:23
    Repairing takes 19 minutes
    Current time is 12:42
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 12:57
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 13:07
    Repairing takes 112 minutes
    Current time is 14:59
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 15:14
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 15:24
    Repairing takes 127 minutes
    Current time is 17:31
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 17:46
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 17:56
    Repairing takes 46 minutes
    Current time is 18:42
    */
}

public void simulateOneDayAndStopOnTimeTest() {
    /*Car c1=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'p', 1800);
    Car c2=new Car("Citroen", "C5 Tourer", 'd', 2300);
    Car c3=new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 'd', 2050);
    Bicycle b1=new Bicycle("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", false);
    Car c4=new Car("MesserSchmidt", "Targa", 'p', 950);
    Car c5=new Car("Hummer", "XL", 'd', 5600);
    Car c6=new Car("BMW", "R3", 'd', 6350);
    Car c7=new Car("Citroen", "C5 Tourer", 'd', 2300);

    GarageSimulation gs=new GarageSimulation();
    gs.addVehicle(c1);
    gs.addVehicle(c2);
    gs.addVehicle(c3);
    gs.addVehicle(b1);
    gs.addVehicle(c4);
    gs.addVehicle(c5);
    gs.addVehicle(c6);
    gs.addVehicle(c7);

    gs.simulateOneDayAndStopOnTime();
    */

    /* Expected outcome
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 8:15
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 8:25
    Repairing takes 36 minutes
    Current time is 9:01
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 9:16
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 9:26
    Repairing takes 46 minutes
    Current time is 10:12
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 10:27
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 10:37
    Repairing takes 41 minutes
    Current time is 11:18
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 11:33
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 11:43
    Repairing takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 11:58
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 12:13
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 12:23
    Repairing takes 19 minutes
    Current time is 12:42
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 12:57
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 13:07
    Repairing takes 112 minutes
    Current time is 14:59
    Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes
    Current time is 15:14
    Visiting the toilet takes 10 minutes
    Current time is 15:24
    Repairing takes 127 minutes
    Current time is 17:31
    Exception: Closing time...
    Still 3 activities pending

    */

}
```

}

GarageSimulation.java

```
  import java.util.*;

public class GarageSimulation{
private int time;
private static final int START_HOUR=8;
private static final int MIN_IN_HOUR=60;
private static final int TOTAL_MINUTES=480; 
private ArrayList<Vehicle> dayplan;
private EatAndDrink eatdrink;
private Toilet toilet;
private RepairVehicle repair;

public GarageSimulation() {

  ArrayList<Vehicle> dayplan = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
  // add eat and drink to dayplanning

  // IT GOES WRONG HERE 

  dayplan.add();// don't know which arguments or how I can add an activity to the arraylist

  // add toilet to dayplanning

  // add repair vehicle to dayplanning

}

public void simulateOneDay() {
  // No clue what im doing here 
  int i = 0;
  while(dayplan.size() > i) {
  // get the activity
  System.out.println(dayplan.get(i));
  System.out.println("Current time is "+showCurrentTime());
  // show the activity and update time

  // Print the current time

  i++;
  }
}

private String showCurrentTime() {
  int hour=START_HOUR+time/MIN_IN_HOUR;
  int min=time%MIN_IN_HOUR;
  if (min<10) 
  return hour+":0"+min;
  else
  return hour+":"+min;
}
}
```

EatAndDrink.java

```
public class EatAndDrink implements Activity{
public int showActivityAndReturnTime() {
    System.out.println("Eating/drinking takes 15 minutes");
    return 15;
}
 }
```

Same shit in Toilet.java

RepairVehicle.java

```
public class RepairVehicle implements Activity{
private int time;

public RepairVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
  Car c = (Car) vehicle;

  if( vehicle instanceof Car){

  //tijd reperatie auto
  if( c.getFueltype() == 'd'){
  time = (c.getContents()/50) * 2;
  }else{
        time = (c.getContents()/50);
  }

  }else if( vehicle instanceof Bicycle){

  time = 15;
  }

}

@Override
public int showActivityAndReturnTime() {
  System.out.println("Repairing takes "+time+" minutes");
  return time;
}
}
```

interface Activity.java

```
public interface Activity
{

public int showActivityAndReturnTime(); 
}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

private char fueltype;
private int contents;

public Car(String brand,String modelname,char fueltype,int contents){
  super(brand,modelname);

  if(fueltype == 'd' || fueltype == 'p'){
  this.fueltype = fueltype;
  }
  if( contents >= 0 ){
  this.contents = contents;
  }else{
  this.contents = 1000;
  }

}

public char getFueltype(){

  return fueltype;
}

public int getContents(){

  return contents;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
  if (this == o){
  return true;
  }
  if(!( o instanceof Car)){
  return false;
  }    

  Car c = (Car) o;

  return(
  c.brand.equals(this.brand) &&
  c.modelname.equals(this.modelname) 
  );

}

}
```

Bicycle.java and Vehicle.java are not really necessary to show here I think.

Hope some of you guys can help me out ! thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get when you compile?

Comment: My error does not really matter ( error: says I cannot use an int argument for an arrayList<String> that's logic ) 

Point being: I have to add the activities in an ArrayList<???> I don't know which ArrayList I need to use? ArrayList<Activity>? or Integer/String/Vehicle ? 

And if I finally found the one. I don't know how to add them to my ArrayList<> thats why I left dayplan.add() empty argument. I tried so many things and none of them are working. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

`dayplan` is declared as

```
private ArrayList<Vehicle> dayplan;
```

and you call the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) method without any arguments.

```
dayplan.add();
```

That is what is causing the compile error.

You need to pass the it an argument, the `vehicle`.

```
dayplan.add(vehicle);
```

Comment: @RafaelvandenBerg sure you have a clue, then you have said in the declaration it should contain `Vehicle`!!! If you don't want to have sub-classes of `Vehicle` then why declare it like this: `private ArrayList<Vehicle> dayplan;`??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with

```
dayplan.add();
```

you should add the vehicle

so change it to

```
dayplan.add(vehicle);
```

Comment: Already tried that and then? But how can I add activity's for each car.

Comment: I think the activities must not be added to Vehicle . it should be added to a new object called worker. let's speak  logically : you have EatAndDrink as an activity , do you think vehicles can eat and drink ?